# Go restrictions on ARM registers R10 and R11

Tags: go, assembly, arm

I am looking to port a highly optimized crypto ASM implementation to Go ASM. The only documentation on Go Arm Assembly is the [Quick Guide](https://golang.org/doc/asm#arm) and it mentioned the following:

- The registers R10 and R11 are reserved by the compiler and linker.
- R10 points to the g (goroutine) structure. Within assembler source code, this pointer must be referred to as g; the name R10 is not recognized.
- Hand-written assembly can use R11, but doing so requires being sure that the linker is not also using it to implement any of the other instructions in the function.

The ASM I am looking to port uses `R10` and `R11` so my question is the following:

- Can I use R10/g?
- If I use R10/g, so long as I store R10 value at the beginning of the call on the stack and then load it at the end, will there be any problems? (assume `go:nosplit` is used to stop preemptive behavior)
- So long as I am not calling any other functions from the Go ASM, then I should not have to worry about the linker restriction on R11, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not touch `R10` in case e.g. your code is preempted or a panic occurs.  I believe the guide is pretty clear on that.

`R11` is used by the linker to synthesise some instructions, e.g. references to global variables.  Best check if `R11` is used by assembling and then disassembling the code.  In the disassembly, any reference to `R11` introduced by the linker should be visible.

Comment: Ignoring the panic case, what if I try to prevent preempted behavior with a `go:nosplit`?

Comment: @LiamKelly You cannot prevent preemption.  `go:nosplit` won't do anything for assembly functions (though placing a `NOSPLIT` in the `TEXT` directive would) but is a red herring anyway.